# Get translations for a string in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a string (in english) in wordpress, that I know has translations in a .po and .mo file, and it shows up correctly translated on the front-end when browsing the site in that language.

However I have a need to get the translation in a PHP script.  Not the .po/.mo file, just the translated string.  Note: I am not talking about displaying text in the current language.

I am looking for a function that I can supply the original string, and a language code, and retrieve the translation.   I will need to do this for all the available languages within one script/request - so it is also acceptable to retrieve all of this data at once.

I have tried something like this as a test ($languages is an array of lang code strings)

```
        foreach ($languages as $language) {
            apply_filters('locale', $language);
            $test = translate($entry_id, 'roots');
            print_r($test);
            print "<hr>";
        }
```

However this seems to just give me the english strings (and en or any variant is not one of the languages in $languages).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I expect that I could process the .po file myself, but this seems unnecessary since wordpress does have the ability to pull translations in the current language using the getText functions commonly used in templating, so I figure there must be a shorter path to what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `global $locale` to "set" a value (you can actually just set define it as anything and then the [`locale`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/locale) filter will be applied).

You can then pass the string that you want to translate into the [`__()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) function. to get the translated value.

```
add_action( 'init', 'init_locale' );
function init_locale(){
    // initialise the global variable on init, set it to whatever you want
    global $locale;
    $locale = "en_US";
}

// use a filter to set the locale
add_filter( 'locale', 'set_locale' );
function set_locale(){
    // whatever logic you want to set the country
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['foo'] ) && $_REQUEST['foo'] == 'spanish' ){
        return 'es_ES';
    }
    // or use the global
    global $locale;
    return $locale;
}

// once everything is loaded you can get the translated text. 
add_function( 'wp_loaded', 'translated_text' );
function translated_text(){
    // you might have used a filter or defined the global somewhere and can use...
    $spanish = __( 'text to translate' );

    // or you could define the global here and then get the text.
    global $locale;
    $locale = 'fr_FR';
    $french = __( 'text to translate' );
}
```

If you want a single function that does it, this should work:

```
function get_translated_text( $text, $domain = 'default', $the_locale = 'en_US' ){
    // get the global
    global $locale;
    // save the current value
    $old_locale = $locale;
    // override it with our desired locale
    $locale = $the_locale;
    // get the translated text (note that the 'locale' filter will be applied)
    $translated = __( $text, $domain );
    // reset the locale
    $locale = $old_locale;
    // return the translated text
    return $translated;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems quite promising, but I've had no luck so far.  I continue to get English strings.   I'm guessing this code only works within a certain context or environment, and I don't know how to set that up in a PHP script.  I have access to the wordpress functions, but from doing some debugging in wp-includes/l10n.php it seems that changing locale with the techniques shown does not have the desired effect.  In this case it's set to "pt_BR" but the l10n functions always try to find the translations in en_US.mo file - which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: mate I'm gonna mark yours as best answer because it is unusual for anyone to try and answer my questions on this site, but I'll also post the solution I used.

Answer (score 4):

In the end I did wind up just processing the .mo file to get the translations, but it was easier than I thought.

```
$translations = array();
$languages = get_available_languages(ABSPATH . '../wp-content/themes/MY-THEME/lang');
foreach ($languages as $language) {
    $mo = new MO();
    if ($mo->import_from_file(ABSPATH . '../wp-content/themes/MY-THEME/lang/' . $language . '.mo')) {
        $translations[$language] = $mo->entries;
    }
}
```

Then the translation is at `$translations[$language][$entry_id]->translations[0]`
where $entry_id is the English string.

Comment: Not sure why I was downvoted.  I am the original poster, and this is the solution that worked.  I guarantee it.